# How to manage recursive function?

Tags: java, recursion

I need  to write a recursive function that gets 4 parameters.

The 1st one is array. the 2nd one  - left index, the 3rd one a right index and "K" index. "K" index is a cell in array , and the lrft index points to the start and the right one points to the end.

An array may contain  such digitalis as zeros and ones. The method returns the maximum length of a sequence of ones that contain the cell k.

Here the example of the result that I need to get:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   int[] A = {1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1};
   System.out.println(floodOnes(A,0, A.length-1, 9)); // 5 output
   System.out.println(floodOnes(A,0, A.length-1, 3)); // 0 output
   System.out.println(floodOnes(A,0, A.length-1, 0)); // 3 output
   System.out.println(floodOnes(A,0, A.length-1, 14)); // 2 output
}

public static int floodOnes(int [] A,int left, int right, int k){
    //some logic
}
```

Here is my implementation:

```
public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] A = {1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1};
        System.out.println(floodOnes(A,0,A.length-1, 9));
    }

    public static int floodOnes(int [] A,int left, int right, int k){           
        if (left != k) left+=1;
        if (right != k) right-=1;   

        if (left == k  && right == k) return A[k]; //condition when the recursive call stops 

        int res = floodOnes(A, left,  right,  k);

        if (A[left] == 1 && A[right] == 1) 
            return res = A[left] + A[right];  //count ones      

        else  return res;   
    }   
}
```

But my solution not working properly.

In this rows:

```
if (A[left] == 1 && A[right] == 1) 
      return res = A[left] + A[right];  //count ones
```

If one of the conditions isn`t executed once, the following returns shouldn't add ones to result variable.

And I don't know how to do it.

Comment: *"write a recursive function that gets **three** parameters"* and then you proceed to write a method with **four** parameters? What's up with that?

Comment: `floodOnes(A,0, A.length-1 9)` is a compile error. Please post valid code, unless you're asking about compile errors.

Comment: @Andreas, it has just been edited.

Comment: Sorry man...I still see a method with four parameters :/

Comment: Your check if (left != k) seems wrong. left has to be <= than k. And I do not think you need the parameter right

Comment: Just looking at the code paths, it's impossible for this method to ever return anything more than a 2.  Either it returns `A[k]` which can't be more than 1, it returns `A[left] + A[right]` which can't be more than 2, or it returns the result of a recursive call, which can't be more than 2 because no base case is ever more than 2.

Comment: @DevilsHnd, sorry I made  a mistake it have to be 4 params

Comment: As far as I can see, it does not make sense to have a recursive method with those 4 parameters solve the problem. Say that a recursive call `floodOnes(arr, 4, 8, 6)` returns 3, so you know there are three ones in a row, but you don’t know whether they are in index 4, 5 and 6 or in 5, 6 and 7 or 6, 7 and 8. So if there is a 1 in index 3, you don’t know whether or not to count it in addition to the 3 you got. The approach in the answer is more promising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are looking for - `the maximum length of a sequence of ones that contain the cell k`. A simple and concise code to achieve this can be as follows.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] A = {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1};
    System.out.println(floodOnes(A, 0, A.length - 1, 9));  // prints 5 
    System.out.println(floodOnes(A, 0, A.length - 1, 3));  // prints 0 
    System.out.println(floodOnes(A, 0, A.length - 1, 0));  // prints 3 
    System.out.println(floodOnes(A, 0, A.length - 1, 14)); // prints 2 
}

public static int checkLeft(int[] A, int k) {
    return (k < 0 || A[k] != 1) ? 0 : 1 + checkLeft(A, k - 1);
}

public static int checkRight(int[] A, int k) {
    return (k > (A.length - 1) || A[k] != 1) ? 0 : 1 + checkRight(A, k + 1);
}

public static int floodOnes(int[] A, int left, int right, int k) {
    return (A[k] != 1) ? 0 : checkLeft(A, k - 1) + 1 + checkRight(A, k + 1);
}
```

It outputs the desired result.

```
5
0
3
2
```

Comment: Basically repeating Grzegorz Górkiewicz’ answer, polishing it a little bit. Apart from all of us possibly being a bit too willing to write the asker’s code, it’s a good answer to copy. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can decompose this problem into 2 functions.
The first will count elements on the left-hand side, the latter on the right-hand side. Both use recursion.

```
public static int floodOnes(int[] A, int left, int right, int k) {
    return checkLeft(A, left, k-1, A[k]) + 1 + checkRight(A, right, k+1, A[k]);
}

public static int checkLeft(int[] A, int leftBoundary, int k, int number) {
    if (k < 0 || A[k] != number || k < leftBoundary)
        return 0;
    return 1 + checkLeft(A, leftBoundary, k-1, number);
}

public static int checkRight(int[] A, int rightBoundary, int k, int number) {
    if(k >= A.length || A[k] != number || k > rightBoundary)
        return 0;
    return 1 + checkRight(A, rightBoundary, k+1, number);
}
```

I assume:
that `0 <= left <= k <= right < A.length`;
that the solitary number should be counted as 1 (sequence of length 1) unlike your example. If you want it to be counted as 0, add `if(A[k] != 1) return 0;` or a similar condition in your `floodOnes` method.

Therefore:

```
System.out.println(floodOnes(A, 0, A.length - 1, 9));  // prints 5 
System.out.println(floodOnes(A, 0, A.length - 1, 3));  // prints 1 
System.out.println(floodOnes(A, 0, A.length - 1, 0));  // prints 3 
System.out.println(floodOnes(A, 0, A.length - 1, 14)); // prints 2
```

Besides `left` and `right` parameters can be used for some input exceptions
(e.g. `k > A.length`).

Answer (score 1):

I proved my comment wrong. Here is a recursive method with the 4 parameters mentioned in the question that indeed solves the problem.

```
public static int floodOnes(int[] a, int left, int right, int k) {
    if (0 <= left && left <= k && k <= right && right < a.length) {
        // is there a 0 between left (inclusive) and k (exclusive)?
        int i = left;
        while (i < k && a[i] == 1) {
            i++;
        }
        if (i < k) {
            assert a[i] == 0;
            return floodOnes(a, i + 1, right, k);
        }
        // is there a 0 between k (exclusive) and right (inclusive)?
        i = right;
        while (i > k && a[i] == 1) {
            i--;
        }
        if (i > k) {
            assert a[i] == 0;
            return floodOnes(a, left, i - 1, k);
        }
        // no zero found, a[k] not checked, though
        if (a[k] == 0) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return right - left + 1;
        }
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected " + left + " <= " + k + " <= " + right + " < " + a.length);
    }
}
```

With this method, the first `main` method in your question prints the expected:

```
5
0
3
2
```

I really don’t see a point in solving the problem in this way, so I am far from sure this was what was intended. I’d prefer a non-recursive solution, or if it just needs to be recursive somehow, then the solution in [Grzegorz Górkiewicz’ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42320874/5772882).

Comment: I would not put so much into the if block. I think throwing the exception should be in the second line of method's body. And you could do without the else block then (and without indentation as a result).